# Gmail Default Routing rule fails silently

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have set up a rule in Gmail Default Routing to redirect any email sent to abc@domain.com (not a valid email address - no emailbox, not an email alias group) to me@domain.com with "From ABC" prepended to the email subject.

This rule appears to work fine for any email sent to abc@domain.com from an external email source (like my personal gmail account) or from an internal email (any other user @domain.com) but silently disappears in two cases:

1. When I (using me@domain.com) send email to abc@domain.com - I would expect it to route to my inbox (just as occurs when I (using me@domain.com) send email to me@domain.com
2. When I have entered abc@domain.com as a "second factor" email in a vendor system - the expected second factor check never arrives at me@domain.com

I have tried adding me@domain.com as an "also deliver to" on this rule (which is rewriting the header with a new recipient of me@domain.com already) - no effect.

I have used Email log search for #1 - I can see the email arriving but it ends up with a "Dropped" status and I can't figure out why that is happening.

I have not yet tried to capture the log behavior of #2.

Any ideas?

[Snip of email log search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbRNZ.png)

See above for relevant details.